# How to move paste range while using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am running 75 iterations in excel. Now, I need a VBA code to copy & paste the results of each iteration. To do this I am using the following code. But, I am not getting the paste function correct here. How to shift the paste range after every iteration so that all the outputs are visible?

```
Copy Range defined as - Range("Sens_Copy_GT").Value (Size: 7 Rows and 10 Columns)
Paste Range defined as- "Sens_Paste_GT"
```

```
Option Explicit
Sub Sens_GT()
Dim j As Variant
For j = Range("FROM").Value To Range("TO").Value
Range("Sens_Reduction").Value = j
Range("Sens_Paste_GT").Offset(j, 0) = Range("Sens_Copy_GT").Value
Next j
Range("Sens_Reduction") = 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Sens_GT()

    Dim j As Long, rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("Sens_Paste_GT")
    For j = Range("FROM").Value To Range("TO").Value
        Range("Sens_Reduction").Value = j
        rng.Resize(7, 10).Value = Range("Sens_Copy_GT").Value
        Set rng = rng.Offset(7)
    Next j
    Range("Sens_Reduction") = 0

End Sub
```